# Power BI Category Change

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I am fairly new with Power BI and could use some help. I have this [Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTVkc.png) which is data bat two different dates

I want to display this as a % movement in each category through a matrix table in Power BI. This is how the [change matrix table looks through Business Objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6721.png)

Example: Beg Category = A, End Volume in A = 1,777,073,616.10. Total Beginning Volume of A = 1,923,868,284.54. So A % movement is 1,777,073,616.10/1,923,868,284.54 = .9237. Repeat this logic for every other end category. The Eliminated % would be Beg Category = A with volume of 1,923,868,284.54. End Volume of all end categories with beginning category A  = 1,800,294,985.85 and difference is 125,573,298.69 divided by beginning total 1,923,868,285 = -6.53%

I currently only have two data points in but ideally I would have multiple month end dates and could then change the start and end date through slicers (I would think?)

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you call this calculation, but create a DAX Measure with this calculation:

```
Elim Ratio = DIVIDE( SUM('Table'[End Vol]), 
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Beg Vol]),ALL('Table'[End Category])) )
```

`DIVIDE` handles pesky divide by 0 errors.
The `CALCULATE` will compute the `SUM` with a filter statement of `ALL('Table'[End Category])`. Because each cell of the table will be filtered to a particular `End Category`, `ALL` removes the filter on `End Category` so you can get the sum of all beginning volumes for the row you're in.

Create a Matrix visual and put `Beg Category` in the Rows and `End Category` in the Columns and the `Elim Ratio` DAX measure in the Values. You can turn off the **Row subtotals** and **Column subtotals** in the visual formatting.

Here's the same measure with your requested "upgrade" and "downgrade" logic:

```
Elim Ratio = 
IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Beg Category]) = "A" &&
   SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[End Category]) = "B",
  -1, --downgrade
  IF(SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Beg Category]) = "B" && 
     SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[End Category]) = "A",
    1, --upgrade
    DIVIDE( SUM('Table'[End Vol]), 
            CALCULATE( SUM('Table'[Beg Vol]), ALL('Table'[End Category]) ) 
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Awesome that worked perfectly! Follow up question if you can. I am trying to now create an if statement so if prior category was A and ending category was B then "downgrade." and opposite if prior category was B and ending cat was A then upgrade.. each A-F do have a numerical (1-6) corresponding value as well,

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "upgrade" and "downgrade", but see the revised measure above. Just substitute your calculations in the proper place.